# How do I remove a profile on Chrome? (Chrome settings only show me a fraction of the profiles that I have)

Tags: google-chrome

How do I remove a profile on Chrome? (Chrome settings only show me a fraction of the profiles that I have)

Chrome has a bunch of profiles created normally that i'm fine with(about 19 i'm fine with). But I also have some profiles created with running chrome with something like the option `"--profile-directory=........"`  When the specified profile doesn't exist, it turns out that it creates it.  I want to delete those.. Also they were created running that command with the wrong format e.g. `--profile-directory="'Profile1'"`  which can or does create a directory with single quotes in it.. anyhow it's a mess. I don't suggest anybody does with single quotes in there. I removed some of the directories it made, which maybe wasn't the right way to remove the profiles.

Anyhow, it gave them names in Chrome like

[image]

When looking up how to remove a profile in Chrome, i found https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

And it said

[image]

If I look in the top right i see two icons that look like profile icons

[image]

The bottom one is from being on google.com so I could go to e.g. [www.dogpile.com](http://www.dogpile.com) then it just shows the top one which I guess is what that link means.

So I click the top one

[image]

These are all my profiles, there's about 24.

[image]

Person 4,5,6,7,8 are the illegitimate ones I want to delete. So about 5/24 I want to delete.

But it only shows me a small number of my profiles, 8 profiles, on the screen when i click settings. That's only about a third of the profiles I have. And none of the ones on the settings screen there are the ones I want to delete

[image]

Comment: What happens if you delete some profiles restart Chrome, and delete more profiles; repeat? You may need to delete a few working profiles

Comment: @John Obviously I don't want to delete profiles that I don't want to delete.!! And as I said, the profiles it shows me on that screen are ones I don't want to delete

Comment: Delete the profile folders for the profiles you want to delete, it’s trivial, to determine which folders belong to those profiles. Your likely at an edge case on the number of profiles you have and should report the bug to Chrome and/or Chromium. If your being offer a way to switch to those profiles then the user profile folders still exist

Comment: @Ramhound well, if I go to the profile of "Person 4",  and do chrome://version it says for profile folder `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile`  So,  is that another bug?  I don't think I should delete the profile folder?

Comment: I just used the feedback feature in chrome to let google know so will see what happens